# Generate private key from insecure public key

Tags: open-source, command-line, ssh

Supposing I have a 512-bit RSA public key (insecure by modern standards), how can I brute force to obtain a valid, corresponding private key assuming I have infinite time?

Suppose:

1. I generate an insecure 512-bit private GPG key

   - `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 512`
2. I extract the public key

   - `cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ssh.pub`
3. I delete the private key

   - `rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. use some tool to factor the public key, or brute force generate until the private key works with the public key

   - I *do not* want to use disk file recovery

How can I do step 4? The tool needs to handle only RSA keys (not ECDSA, for example).

It needs to work on Linux (Ubuntu), be open source, and does not require AWS (for example, [factoring as a service](https://github.com/eniac/faas)). It should have a command line interface.